# How can I get the maximum value on string between a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi StackOverflow Community.

I have the following table with two tables "id" (integer) and "num_pot" (varchar 255) with the following data information:

```
|transformers|
  |id|  |num_pot|
    1     1.0
    2     2.12/6
    3     5/6/8
    4     2.9/40
    5     2.1
```

Here is the transformer_controller.rb, it displays all registries

```
def index
   @transformers = Transformer.all
end
```

I'm trying to display the following information on my array view index.html.erb

```
<% @transformers.each do |array| %>
  <%= array.num_pot %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to create the code to check on strings and compare on the column num_pot:

```
|num_pot|
  1.0       # CHECK THE GREATEST VALUE = 1.0
  2.12/6    # CHECK THE GREATEST VALUE = 6
  5/6/8     # CHECK THE GREATEST VALUE = 8
  2.9/40    # CHECK THE GREATEST VALUE = 40
  2.1       # CHECK THE GREATEST VALUE = 2.1
```

How can I display the following data (the maximum value on string):

```
|num_pot|
  1.0
  6
  8
  40
  2.1
```

I tried the following code using "**max**" but I got error:

```
<% @transformers.each do |array| %>
  <%= array.num_pot.max(1) %>
<% end %>

undefined method `max' for "2.12/6":String
```

I would appreciate any comments about it

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you should consider storing your data in a way that doesn't have composite values. (see [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in your `num_pod` column are as you already wrote – strings and not a list of numbers. That means, to only render one of the values and only the biggest of them, you first need to split the string into its parts. And then translate the parts into floats to be able to compare and pick the biggest value.

Let's take this example:

```
'5.2/6/8'.split('/')
#=> ['5.2', '6', '8']

'5.2/6/8'.split('/').map(&:to_f)
#=> [5.2, 6, 8]

'5.2/6/8'.split('/').map(&:to_f).max
#=> 8
```

The last two steps can be simplified to just `max_by(&:to_f)`, because in your case it would be okay, to compare them values by their float value but to return their string values to be rendered.

Using this, you should get the expected result by changing the view to:

```
<% @transformers.each do |transformer| %>
  <%= transformer.num_pot.split('/').max_by(&:to_f) %>
<% end %>
```

**Or**, to make it easier to read in the view and reusable, add this method to your `Transformer` model in `app/models/transformer.rb`:

```
def max_num_pot
  num_pot.split('/').max_by(&:to_f)
end
```

And change the view to:

```
<% @transformers.each do |transformer| %>
  <%= transformer.max_num_pot %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me . That's what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

What's about using SQL in this case?

Prepare all data inside controller

```rb
@transformers =
  Transformer
    .select("*, (SELECT max(ary) FROM unnest(string_to_array(num_pot, '/')::numeric[]) AS ary) AS max_value")
```

And render in the view

```
<% @transformers.each do |transformer| %>
  <%= array.max_value %>
<% end %>
```

Here you can see online DB fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hEETjWuvr9sc5k4XfMeH8w/0

And how it works:

```sql
SELECT
  *, —- select all real columns
  (
    SELECT max(ary) —- select maximum value from array
    FROM unnest( —- convert array to "set of rows"
      string_to_array(num_pot, '/')::numeric[] —- split string by slash to numeric array
    ) AS ary —- alias for array
  ) AS max_value —- select calculated max value as max_value virtual column
FROM transformers;
```